# delete record from another model on action select in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using `Django 2.0`

I have created few `actions` to use in `admin` interface

```
def clear_arbitrase(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(arbitrase_generated=False)


@admin.register(WallmartRecord)
class WallmartRecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [
        clear_arbitrase
    ]
```

This updates, the `arbitrase_generated` flag to `False` for `WallmartRecord` model.

I have another table to save record of `arbitrase` in `ArbitraseRecord`

I want to delete record from `ArbitraseRecord` as well when flagging `arbitrase_generated` to `False`.

I tried implementing `post_save` signal in `models.py`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=WallmartRecord)
def post_save_wallmart_record_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.arbitrase_generated:
        # delete records from ArbitraseRecord
        arbitrase_record = ArbitraseRecord.objects.filter(wallmart_record=instance)
        if arbitrase_record is not None:
            for record in arbitrase_record:
                record.delete()
```

But this seems be to not calling receiver.

**How can I delete record from another model on admin action select?**

Answer (score 0):

`update()`  performs on SQL level directly and it's not calling model's `save()`, so `post_save` signal will not be triggered in your case. You can move deletion into `clear_arbitrase` like this:

```
def clear_arbitrase(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(arbitrase_generated=False)
    ArbitraseRecord.objects.filter(wallmart_record__id__in=queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)).delete()
```

Comment: not working. record is not deleting from `ArbitraseRecord`

Comment: on `print(queryset.values_list('id', flat=True))` it is giving empty list `<QuerySet []>`

Comment: @AnujTBE did you select any objects in admin? You can perform action anly after selection.

Comment: Yes I did, `update()` is working on selected objects but not delete

Comment: @AnujTBE does you implement `clear_arbitrase` same as in my answer? Probably somewhere in your code you everride `queryset` variable?

Comment: This time I just copied and pasted your code without any modification. Still not working